# SQL return values from one table depending on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables - `IdentificationChallenges` and `IdentificationResults`.

The challenges table shows a list of challenges and the results table stores a users attempt at the challenge.

I need a query to return all challenges that the user hasn't attempted (where the user id doesn't exist in the results table). My attempt at this is as follows:

```
SELECT ic.*
from IdentificationChallenges ic
LEFT JOIN IdentificationResults ir ON ic.Id = ir.ChallengeId
WHERE ir.UserId != 'cfc1d26c-c091-4b17-aaa3-31e8f5232cf9'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

It does not retrieve any records. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**IdentificationChallenges**

```
Id | ChallengeDateTime | ImageUrl | Description
```

**IdentificationResults**

```
Id | ChallengeId | UserId | ChallengeResult | ResultDateTime
```

Comment: If the user doesn't exist, then you can't use `ir.UserId = ` because `ir.UserId` will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists` to get a list of challenges for a specific user which they have yet to complete. The reason is, in your join, you're actually looking for cases where `ir.UserId is null` but that won't return a list relevant to the specific user. The following should do what you need.

```
DECLARE @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'cfc1d26c-c091-4b17-aaa3-31e8f5232cf9';

SELECT IC.*
FROM dbo.IdentificationChallenges IC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.IdentificationResults IR
    WHERE IR.ChallengeId = IC.Id
    AND IR.UserId = @ID
)
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your `WHERE` condition as `WHERE ir.UserId IS NULL`. It will return all challenges that the user hasn't attempted. Also update `ON` and use `ic.Id = ir.ChallengeId AND ir.UserId = 'cfc1d26c-c091-4b17-aaa3-31e8f5232cf9'` to get `challanges` attempted by `user`.

```
SELECT ic.*
FROM IdentificationChallenges ic
LEFT JOIN IdentificationResults ir 
    ON ic.Id = ir.ChallengeId
        AND ir.UserId = 'cfc1d26c-c091-4b17-aaa3-31e8f5232cf9'
WHERE ir.UserId IS NULL
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join for the results from that user, and use the `WHERE` to check that no match has been found.

```
SELECT ic.*
from IdentificationChallenges ic
     LEFT JOIN IdentificationResults ir ON ic.Id = ir.ChallengeId and 
                                           ir.UserId = 'cfc1d26c-c091-4b17-aaa3-31e8f5232cf9'
WHERE ir.Id is null
```

PS: why do you `order by newid()` when you don't return that newly created id on the result?

Comment: `order by newid()` I assume will return the challenges in a random order...